# reference javascript content coming from db instead of static file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developping an asp.net web application :

In the website folder, I have a folder called "integrations" containing a list of js files (name1.js, name2.js, name3.js ...)

A user makes a http request to a mvc controller method where he gives as input a "name".
This method gives the "name" as a property of a viewmodel to a razor view containing the following code :
    
This razor view is returned to the user.

The previous code is working well, but I would like to add an improvment. Actually you need to add a js file inside the folder integrations,
and you cannot do that when the application is running in production.
So I would like instead of having a script tag referencing a file placed inside the integrations folder to have a script tag containing a js content
coming from a data table like this :
name : jscontent
name1 : jscontent1
name2 : jscontent2

But I don't know how to changed this :

```
<script src="~/integrations/@(Model.Name).js"></script>
```

To :

```
<script>>query in db by @(Model.Name) parameter to get corresponding jscontent</script>
```

Comment: Just make another view with a model containing what you need and then use `<script src="controller/view"></script>`

Comment: so I will have a method controller receiving in parameter a name, querying in db the js content according to this name, and returning the js content ? I think this won't work cause the src is expecting a javascript static file and not javascript content coming from db

Answer (score 0):

Make it a controller/method and you can take advantage of things like caching, auth etc for free:

```
public class ScriptController
{
  public ActionResult Content(MyModel model)
  {
    var result = "alert("Hello World!");";
    return JavaScript(result);
  }
}
```

[JavaScriptResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_JavaScript_System_String_)

Then in your html:

```
<script src="~/Script/Content?prop1=whatever"></script>
```

Comment: ok thanks for your quick and clean answer. Will try it. Just a related question, do you know if it's better to store the javascript file in a plain text column (varchar) or binary column(blob) ?